# Testing welcome paragraph to equal to "welcome" instead of empty string

Tags: javascript, jestjs, jsdom, testing-library

I am using jest, jsdom and testing-libray/dom to test this page (index.html). i expect paragraph to be  "welcome" but i am getting empty string ("") because a page (index.html) is loading before javascript.

I would like to ask if there are other ways to do it. thanks.

this is how my code looks like.
**index.html**

```
<html>
<body>
<p data-testid="paragraph"></p>

<script type="text/javascript">
const p = document.querySelector("p");
p.textContent = "welcome";
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**index.test.js**

```
const { getByTestId } = require("@testing-library/dom");
const { JSDOM } = require("jsdom");
require("@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect");
const path = require("path");
const fs = require("fs");
let dom;
let container;

const html = fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, "./index.html"));

describe("index", () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    dom = new JSDOM(html, { runScripts: "dangerously" });
    container = dom.window.document.body;
  });

  it("should display welcome text", () => {
    const pEl = getByTestId(container, "paragraph");

    expect(pEl.textContent).toEqual("welcome");
  });
});
```

screenshoot
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AJtiI.png)
thanks

Comment: Have you tried using [`findBy*` queries](https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-async#findby-queries) instead?